# Spring mvc DELETE WITH classic POST (@PostMapping) not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

hi i'm testing a fast crud with spring mvc using classic methods as forms types

the error is this

```
org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException: No class 
com.project.springinventory.entity.Customers entity with id 0 exists!
        at 
org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.delete(SimpleJpaRepository.java:154) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
```

looks like the object is not receiving anything

checked anything and looks ok I don't know what to do

as you can see I'm receiving id and obtaining all fields from DB
is there a manner I can use this method without changing it? (using form)

[image: Click here to view image]

VIEW

```html
<table class="table table-bordered">
 <tr>
  <th><span>Id</span></th>
  <th><span>Course</span></th>
  <th><span>Name</span></th>
  <th><span>Last Name</span></th>
  <th><span>Address</span></th>
  <th><span>Actions</span></th>
 </tr>
 <tr th:each="customer:${customers}">
  <th><span th:text="${customer.id}"></span></th>
  <th><span th:text="${customer.firstname}"></span></th>
  <th><span th:text="${customer.lastname}"></span></th>
  <th><span th:text="${customer.course}"></span></th>
  <th><span th:text="${customer.address}"></span></th>
  <th>
   <form th:action="@{/showCustomer}" th:object="${customers}" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="btnInsert" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add" />
   </form>
   <form th:action="@{/UpdateCustomer}" th:object="${customers}" method="post">
    <button class="btn btn-warning">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true">Edit</span>
    </button>
   </form>
   <form th:action="@{/DeleteCustomer}" th:object="${customers}" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="btnInsert" class="btn btn-primary" value="Delete" />
   </form>
     </th>
 </tr>
 <form action="#" th:action="@{/customermanagement}" th:object="${CustomersAdd}" method="post">
  <tr>
   <td><input type="text" placeholder="Course"
    th:field="*{course}" /></td>
   <td><input type="text" placeholder="Name"
    th:field="*{firstname}" /></td>
   <td><input type="text" placeholder="Last Name"
    th:field="*{lastname}" /></td>
   <td><input type="text" placeholder="Address"
    th:field="*{address}" /></td>
   <td><input type="submit" name="btnInsert"
    class="btn btn-primary" value="Add" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>
    <p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('course')}" th:errors="*{course}">course
     has errors</p>
   </td>
   <td>
    <p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('firstname')}"
     th:errors="*{firstname}">firstname has errors</p>
   </td>
   <td>
    <p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('lastname')}"
     th:errors="*{lastname}">lastname has errors</p>
   </td>
   <td>
    <p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('address')}"
     th:errors="*{address}">address has errors</p>
   </td>
  </tr>    
 </form>
</table>
```

CONTROLLER

```
@PostMapping("/DeleteCustomer")
        public ModelAndView DeleteUser(@ModelAttribute("customers") Customers 
        Customers) {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();

        System.err.println("Deleting:");
        System.err.println("getId " + Customers.getId());
        System.err.println("getCourse " + Customers.getCourse().toString());
        System.err.println("getCourse " + Customers.getFirstname().toString());
        System.err.println("getLastname " + Customers.getLastname().toString());
        System.err.println("getAddress " + Customers.getAddress().toString());
        customersService.removeCustomer(Customers.getId());
        customersService.listAllCustomers();
        mav.setViewName("redirect:/" + MAIN_VIEW);
        return mav;

    }

SERVICE

    public interface CustomersService {

    public abstract List<Customers> listAllCustomers();
    public abstract Customers addCustomer(Customers customers);
    public abstract int removeCustomer(int  id);
    public abstract Customers updateCustomer(Customers customers);

}
```

SERVICE IMPLEMENTATION

```
    package com.project.springinventory.services;

    import java.util.List;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

    import com.project.springinventory.entity.Customers;
    import com.project.springinventory.repository.CustomersJpaRepository;

    @Service("customersServiceImpl")
    public class CustomersServiceImpl implements CustomersService {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("customersJpaRepository")
    private CustomersJpaRepository customersJpaRepository;  

    @Override
    public List<Customers> listAllCustomers() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return  customersJpaRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public Customers addCustomer(Customers customers) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return customersJpaRepository.save(customers);
    }

    @Override
    public int removeCustomer(int id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        customersJpaRepository.delete(id);
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Customers updateCustomer(Customers customers) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return customersJpaRepository.save(customers);
    }

''

}
```

Literally everything is working exception the DELETE

Comment: Post your `Customers` entity.

Comment: here is https://codepaste.net/4auewu

Answer (score 1):

The controller will receive a empty `Customers` because you are not sending any data back to controller.
I hope you are using Thymeleaf as templating engine.

Try like this

```
<form th:action="@{/DeleteCustomer}" th:object="${CustomersDelete}" method="post">
  <input type="submit" name="btnInsert" class="btn btn-primary" value="Delete" />
 <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}" value="${customer.id}"/> 
</form>
```

Here you are sending `id` back to controller,While submitting the form.

Few changes as well.

```
@GetMapping("/customermanagement")
    public ModelAndView View() {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        mav.addObject("customers", customersService.listAllCustomers());
        mav.addObject("CustomersDelete", new Customers());
        mav.setViewName(MAIN_VIEW);

        return mav;
    }



@PostMapping("/DeleteCustomer")
    public ModelAndView DeleteUser(@ModelAttribute("CustomersDelete") Customers Customers) {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();

        System.err.println("Deleting:");
        System.err.println("getId " + Customers.getId());
        System.err.println("getCourse " + Customers.getCourse().toString());
        System.err.println("getCourse " + Customers.getFirstname().toString());
        System.err.println("getLastname " + Customers.getLastname().toString());
        System.err.println("getAddress " + Customers.getAddress().toString());
        customersService.removeCustomer(Customers.getId());
        customersService.listAllCustomers();
        mav.setViewName("redirect:/" + MAIN_VIEW);
        return mav;
}
```

Comment: org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'id' of bean class [java.util.ArrayList]: Bean property 'id' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?

Comment: <form th:action="@{/DeleteCustomer}" th:object="${customers}"
        method="post">
        <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}" value="${customer.id}"/> 
        <input type="submit" name="btnInsert" class="btn btn-primary"
         value="Delete" />
       </form>

Comment: OMG..it got bind with arraylist.. Please change `th:object` to `th:object="${customer}` I omitted a `s`.

Comment: org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'id' of bean class [java.util.ArrayList]: Bean property 'id' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter? got same

Comment: btw i'm using th:object={customers} because my entity is that, customer variable in the each cycle is only used in html to "draw" the data, here is the entity, if you need more like service, and some stuff, let me know i'll bring it to you :) https://codepaste.net/4auewu

Comment: Thank you for your interest in help me!

Comment: did you change `th:object="${customers}` to `th:object="${customer}`. And post your controller (listing the table) code in the question.

Comment: https://www.paste.org/90912 Here is controller function and htlml with all changed

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'customer' available as request attribute

Comment: http://prntscr.com/ie3s57 deleted value just left th field and the id goes!, but then.. when i send it to the field it says null

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
 at com.project.springinventory.controller.UserManagementController.DeleteUser(UserManagementController.java:69) ~[classes/:na]

Comment: and receiving Deleting:
getId 0

Comment: (no id 0, id is 1)

Comment: ` public ModelAndView DeleteUser(@ModelAttribute("customer") Customers Customers) {` should be `public ModelAndView DeleteUser(@ModelAttribute("CustomersDelete") Customers Customers) {`

Comment: `@ModelAttribute("CustomersDelete") Customers ` you put `customer` instead 'CustomersDelete'

Comment: Do as it in the answer..  change `/customermanagement`  and  `/DeleteCustomer`

Comment: Ongoing! i'm on it

Comment: Still getting error"  Deleting:
getId 0

2018-02-13 08:52:34.702 ERROR 1276 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
 at com.project.springinventory.controller.UserManagementController.DeleteUser(UserManagementController.java:70) ~[classes/:na]"

Comment: https://paste.ofcode.org/32bcpWphTZLZbrYPuVv24E Still getting the same :/ i'm thinking ill try another form, just wanted to use classical post because don't wanted to use a Rest controller, this was a very basic test site for course purposes

Comment: `<input type="text" th:value="${customers.id}" />` to `<input type="text" th:value="${customer.id}" />` and remove all System.err.println .

Comment: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E: Property or field 'id' cannot be found on null

Comment: <tr th:each="customers:${customers}">

Comment: it would be <input type="text" th:value="${customers.id}" />

Comment: deleted all syserr just in case and got this

Comment: org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException: No class com.project.springinventory.entity.Customers entity with id 0 exists!

Comment: gimme ur full html as weel.

Comment: `<input type="text" th:value="${customer.id}" />` it will work.. try

Comment: yeah, it works, the id comes but when i send it to postmapping  delete.. it crash on error..  check this screencap http://prntscr.com/ie4bck

Comment: org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException: No class com.project.springinventory.entity.Customers entity with id 0 exists!
 at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.delete(SimpleJpaRepository.java:154) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.10.RELEASE.jar:na]

Comment: Can you sysout .Print only id

Comment: Add 'th:field' as shown in the answer.. it should work.. inside input.. as shown in answer

Comment: this is my latest html code https://paste.ofcode.org/6tqKURAuZzf8QmcrSLxeCg

Comment: Why are you changing th:value it should be customer.id   not customers.id

Comment: it doesn't affect nothing, just changed th object from th customer to customers, and all the others, just for better comprehension

Comment: however, put back from customers to customer (as i started) i mean this part of the html code <tr th:each="customer:${customers}">  i changed to
<tr th:each="customers:${customers}">  but put back again for avoid misunderstandings but still not working :/

Comment: I am saying about th:value rest remains same..Just do as in answer.

Comment: Now is customer.id but still having the same error, this error have me out of my mind

Comment: i did, but still having the same stuff here is a snippet of the actual code https://paste.ofcode.org/XZD2bnp3dkkDnU6LLbjJPv

Comment: i'm following all piece by piece as the answer but still

Comment: Sysout.print gives you 0??

Comment: Here it is https://paste.ofcode.org/vgAJDhXbHjrVaqB349Masa , i'm really thankfull about your help i hope i could resolve this but i'm like 6 hours on it before posting it

Comment: it's the th field <input type="text"  th:field="*{id}" />  not grabbing the  th:value="${customer.id}" because i tried something new now, just used 2 input 1 <input type="text"  th:field="*{id}" />  and 2   <input type="text"  th:value="${customer.id}" /> at the same time, first input have value 0 and the seccond have value 1 , if i change 0 for 1 and excecute delete it does!, in fact it did, so registry 1 is deleted successfully so the delete logic in fact is working good... the problem here i've got is with the  th:field="*{id}"  which is not working like it supposed to do..

Comment: because th:field="*{id}"  should obtain the value from   th:value="${customer.id}" but it's not doing it for... no reason